# download file using a button in extjs

Tags: button, extjs, download, handler

In a formpanel i have a download button

```
{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Download CSV',
                        style: 'margin:18px 0 0 10px',
                        handler: function () {
                            console.log('download data');
                        }

                    }
```

i want to download: export.csv when i click on this button. I tried to do it with

```
window.open('export.csv','download')
```

this is working in chrome, ff and ie9. But in ie8 it is not working unless you change a setting in the browser. Is there a better way to download a file using buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to force a file download is to use a proxy on the server. In general you'd pass the filename to the proxy and it in turn streams out the MIME header and the file.

You can't really do that with EXT though. How you do that will depend on your server-side platform.

See: [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=force+download](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=force%20download)